# Updating mysql database

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I have one table with columns:

```
id    reg      mSent      text
1     reg1      0         test1
2     reg2      0         test1
3     reg3      0         test1
4     reg1      0         test
```

I want to update `mSent='1'`  with condition `reg=reg1` and `text=text1`
my sql statement is

```
UPDATE `table` SET mSent='1' where textMessage='test1' and reg='reg1'
```

but with no success

Comment: Can You Please Provide the Code What You have tried.....

Comment: Are you getting any errors? There's a discrepancy in your code: `text` and `textMessage`?

Comment: Im trying to execute the sql statement  in mysql database. When i give only one condition for example UPDATE `table` SET mSent='1' where text='test1' it updates all rows with text='test1' but i want  when text='test1' and reg='reg1'

Comment: no im not getting errors (0 rows affected)

Comment: i dont have error with my sql it just wont update (0 rows affected)

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo in your `WHERE` condition, you specify field "textMessage", but apparently you meant "text":

```
UPDATE `table` SET mSent='1' where `text`='test1' and `reg`='reg1'
```